# Can an outlook add-in have multiple pages? Such as a login page that navigates the user to another page that displays info

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am creating an outlook add-in that captures the content of an email and sends it to a messaging system (similar to "share on teams" addin). This messaging system requires the user to enter username and password. I wanted to know if add-in supports multiple pages, that is, login page navigating to another page and so on. Or should everything be present on a single page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as many web pages as you need. You may treat it as a regular web based application. Take a look at the [Overview of authentication and authorization in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/overview-authn-authz) section which describes possible techniques (for example, SSO) that can be used from Office add-ins.

However, be aware that the same-origin policy enforced by the browser or webview control prevents a script loaded from one domain from getting or manipulating properties of a webpage from another domain. This means that, by default, the domain of a requested URL must be the same as the domain of the current webpage. Because Office Add-ins are hosted in a webview control, the same-origin policy applies to script running in their web pages as well.

The same-origin policy can be an unnecessary handicap in many situations, such as when a web application hosts content and APIs across multiple subdomains. There are a few common techniques for securely overcoming same-origin policy enforcement. The [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations) article can provide the briefest introduction to some of them.

Also you may consider using the `Dialog API` for your tasks, see [Authenticate and authorize with the Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api) for more information.